# Mojolicious set HTTP params for controller artificially

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I use Mojolicious command for testing a controller function. This function looks like this:

```
sub process_order {
    # controller object
    my $c = shift;

    my $id = $c->param('id');
    # process data
}
```

Is it possible to artificially set the params for the controller inside a command:

```
sub run {
    my ($self, @args) = @_;

    $self->app->controller_class('Base::Controller');
    my $c = $self->app->build_controller;

    set_http_param('id', 1); # ?
    $c->process_order();
}
```

I am using a different database for testing and not all the tables are present there, so it would be nice if I could setup some artificial environment for the controller.

Comment: https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Controller#stash ?

Comment: @k-mx No, this is for temporary data storage during the session. It doesn't affect HTTP parameters.

Comment: $c->param( id => 9000 ) ?